# Stability of numerical algorithm for computing $e$

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-mathematics

Let an algorithm compute $e$ by $e=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!$ (assume that $fl(k)=k$). The last term of this summation will satisfy $1/k! < \epsilon_{mach}$.

My attempt at solution:

Let $m$ be the last term in the discrete summation. Then

$fl(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^m fl(1/k!)(1+\epsilon_1)=(1+\epsilon_1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^m 1/k! (m(1+\epsilon_2))\le (1+2\epsilon_{mach})\sum\limits_{k=0}^m 1/k! + O(\epsilon_{mach}^2)$

Which means the algorithm is stable, but not backward stable (since we have $1+2\epsilon_{mach}$ instead of $1+\epsilon_{mach}$). I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if my solution is correct. I'm concerned that the last inequality only shows that the algorithm is *at least* stable, which may include backward stability.

Comment: Have you studied the error analysis of a general sum?

Comment: No, I have not. Thanks, I'll look it up.

Comment: A few things continue to puzzle me about your question. There is an obvious typo which you should clear up: "since we have $1+2\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$ instead of $1+2\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$", i.e. repetition of the exact same string. Much more important is the resolution of the following issue. Stability measures the sensitivity of the output to small changes in the input. Here there is really no input to change, right? However, if you consider computing $e^x$ using a truncated Taylor polynomial, then the question of stability becomes much more relevant.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you very much for pointing that out, I have edited my question now. If my subsequent solution was correct, it indicates that there is a dependency on the number of terms in the summation. It appears that the order of the error is about $m\epsilon$. But since there shouldn't be more than 50 terms for the summation of $e$ in this case, i found the algorithm to be stable.